# Angular 10: Dynamic value in outlet routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following routerlink that works:

```
<a 
[routerLink]="['/cases', { outlets: { detailOutlet: 'detail/3' } }]">
Case Detail</a>
```

Notice the hard coded "detail/3"

The Component this template is in has:

```
id:3;
```

How do I get the "id" into the link so that it's dynamic and not hard coded?

Comment: please share your routing code

Answer (score 1):

try this -
you can create your string using the `dynamic id`

```html
<a 
[routerLink]="['/cases', { outlets: { detailOutlet: 'detail/"+id+"' } }]">
Case Detail</a>
```

in this case if your id = 3
your string will be

```html
"['/cases', { outlets: { detailOutlet: 'detail/3' } }]"
```